# QML StatusBar in the upper portion of ApplicationWindow - why?

Tags: qml

I have following QML's `ApplicationWindow`:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import QtTest 1.1

import "gui/windows"
import "gui/items"

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: ueWindowMain

    title: qsTr("testApp")

    width: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth
    height: Screen.desktopAvailableWidth

    visible: true

    opacity: 1.0

    contentOrientation: Qt.LandscapeOrientation

    color: "black"

    UeKeypad
    {
        id: ueLoginKeypad
    }   // ueLoginKeypad

    StatusBar
    {
        id: ueStatusBar

        RowLayout
        {
            spacing: 8

            UeStatusIndicator
            {
                id: ueStatusIndicatorDatabaseConnected

                ueParamImageStatusOn: "qrc:///ueIcons/icons/ueDbConnectionOk.png"
                ueParamImageStatusOff: "qrc:///ueIcons/icons/ueDbConnectionError.png"
            }   // ueStatusIndicatorDatabaseConnected
        }   // RowLayout
    }   // ueStatusBar
}   // ueWindowMain
```

And here is screenshot:
[image: Status Bar Wrong poisiton]

As you can see, I've added QML `StatusBar` into QML `ApplicationWindow`, but `StatusBar` is not positioned in the lower part of `ApplicationWindow`, but in upper. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may give you a hint:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    statusBar: StatusBar {
        RowLayout {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Label { text: "Read Only" }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: F...! I see it! LOL now I will get punished with downvotes! :D

Comment: If you need more info, you can check this  http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-statusbar.html about the oficial documentation